# rake assets:precompile > Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "}": expected "}", was ""

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

I was running:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile --trace
```

Then I get this error stack:

```
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute assets:precompile
rake aborted!
Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "}": expected "}", was ""
(sass):40696
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/gems/sass-3.4.13/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1165:in `expected'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/gems/sass-3.4.13/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1101:in `expected'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/gems/sass-3.4.13/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1096:in `tok!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/gems/sass-3.4.13/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:643:in `block'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/gems/sass-3.4.13/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:401:in `media_directive'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/gems/sass-3.4.13/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:219:in `special_directive'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/gems/sass-3.4.13/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:194:in `directive'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/gems/sass-3.4.13/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:660:in `block_child'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/gems/sass-3.4.13/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:653:in `block_contents'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/gems/sass-3.4.13/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:117:in `stylesheet'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/gems/sass-3.4.13/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:42:in `parse'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/gems/sass-3.4.13/lib/sass/engine.rb:393:in `_to_tree'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/gems/sass-3.4.13/lib/sass/engine.rb:268:in `render'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/gems/sprockets-3.0.2/lib/sprockets/sass_compressor.rb:55:in `block in call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/gems/sprockets-3.0.2/lib/sprockets/cache.rb:85:in `fetch'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/gems/sprockets-3.0.2/lib/sprockets/sass_compressor.rb:48:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/gems/sprockets-3.0.2/lib/sprockets/sass_compressor.rb:27:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/gems/sprockets-3.0.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/gems/sprockets-3.0.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/gems/sprockets-3.0.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/gems/sprockets-3.0.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/gems/sprockets-3.0.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:103:in `load_asset_by_uri'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/gems/sprockets-3.0.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:40:in `block in load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/gems/sprockets-3.0.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:171:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/gems/sprockets-3.0.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:33:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/gems/sprockets-3.0.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/gems/sprockets-3.0.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `yield'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/gems/sprockets-3.0.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/gems/sprockets-3.0.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:63:in `find_asset'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/gems/sprockets-3.0.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:70:in `find_all_linked_assets'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/gems/sprockets-3.0.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:138:in `block in find'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/gems/sprockets-3.0.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in logical_paths'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/gems/sprockets-3.0.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:223:in `block in stat_tree'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/gems/sprockets-3.0.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:207:in `block in stat_directory'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/gems/sprockets-3.0.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:204:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/gems/sprockets-3.0.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:204:in `stat_directory'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/gems/sprockets-3.0.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:222:in `stat_tree'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/gems/sprockets-3.0.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/gems/sprockets-3.0.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `block in logical_paths'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/gems/sprockets-3.0.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/gems/sprockets-3.0.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `logical_paths'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/gems/sprockets-3.0.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:136:in `find'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/gems/sprockets-3.0.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:162:in `compile'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.4/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:70:in `block (3 levels) in define'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/gems/sprockets-3.0.2/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:147:in `with_logger'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.4/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:69:in `block (2 levels) in define'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/gems/rake-10.4.2/bin/rake:33:in `'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/bin/rake:23:in `'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
```

I am using a bought template and seems that this error is been caused by a .css among thousands.

How can I trace the exact place where the error is happening?

The `(sass):40696` in the stack means the last line in the compiled .css

Thank you

Comment: It means you're short a curly brace somewhere.  Start matching them up, remove blocks of code as necessary to track it down.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can check the syntax of your files by running `sass -c app/assets/stylesheets`. That might detect the issue for you.

Comment: It is a little bit tough, I am not finding a recursive way, but it's definitely what I was looking for, thank you.

Comment: You can also specify wildcards like `sass -c app/assets/stylesheets/**.css*`

Comment: @RyanMontgomery does it check recursively? If not is there any way to check for recursive folders? Thanks in advance

Comment: @RyanMontgomery How to use sass -c app/assets/stylesheets this in my rails application? i am not understand properly i face same issue in rails 5.2.1 version

Answer (score 0):

I have observed similar error with the '[freelancer](http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/freelancer/)' template in rails 4. It is the problem with template CSS file

With the following code, I got **Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "...orm-group::not(": expected pseudo_expr, was ":first-child)"** error.

```
.floating-label-form-group::not(:first-child) {
    padding-left: 14px;
    border-left: 1px solid #eee;
}
```

However, after placing double quotes around "first child", it resolved the issue.

```
.floating-label-form-group::not(":first-child") {
    padding-left: 14px;
    border-left: 1px solid #eee;
}
```

Comment: This generates invalid CSS.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me. That solved my SASS problem. Sorry, I didn't check the CSS. How about placing single quotes?

Comment: Why are you asking me?  Validate it yourself.